# What is the trailing x

Tags: directx, terminology, xserver, physx

I noticed that their are a lot of technologies that uses **X** in their names like **Directx** and **PhysX** and **X server** ... is there a something common? Or is there any reason to choose X?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX), the X in DirectX 'stands in' for the various Direct APIs - Direct3D, DirectSound, DirectPlay etc.  Seems like a reasonable explanation.

PhysX probably plays on the whole DirectX 'thing' - but I expect it's named as such 'cause it sounds a bit like physics.

[X Server serves X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System).  :p

Comment: The previous comment would make more sense if you knew that one of my initials is indeed 'A'. But since you don't know that, what can you do?

Comment: @Will A Totland?!?!  Pleased to meet you Will.  :)

Comment: Well, it's A. Will Totland; but that's a detail. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the X varies by usage; in PhysX it seems to be the kewl[sic] way to spell Physics; whereas in X Server (part of the X Window System) takes it's name from being the natural evolution of a system named W (probably short for Window, or just the letter after V; the name of the system on which it ran).

DirectX has already been explained in another answer; so there's that.

But the main reason, most of the time; is that Poor Literacy Is Kewl[sic].

Comment: 'eck, that's an xcellent answer, eggspert!  +1